# New ffmpeg build issue: libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi

ffmpeg build error:
Raspberry Pi 4 B+,
Raspberry Pi OS Buster 32bit

Two years back I built ffmpeg successfully with same script on the same setup.
Now I try building new version ffmpeg 5.0, I get below error and build fails.

I nearly tried more than 10 times with even many other OS version.
Raspberry Pi OS Buster 32bit
Raspberry Pi OS Bullseys 32bit
Raspberry Pi OS Bullseys 64bit

I even tried many scripts:
https://github.com/NRCHKB/nrchkb-ffmpeg-build
https://github.com/NRCHKB/nrchkb-ffmpeg-build/discussions/11
https://github.com/NRCHKB/nrchkb-ffmpeg-build/discussions/11#discussioncomment-5008967
https://gist.github.com/milankragujevic/bd38d796ea6eea27f229216d75d6c202
https://gist.github.com/wildrun0/86a890585857a36c90110cee275c45fd#file-compile-ffmpeg-sh

Almost all are showing same error at the end.
Should I doubt the latest ffmpeg git source ?
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git

All showing same error on the files:
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c

No solution found on the internet on my searches
It will be highy appreciated if some ffmpeg experts solve this issue.

```
./config.h:594: warning: "CONFIG_HARDCODED_TABLES" redefined
 #define CONFIG_HARDCODED_TABLES 1

In file included from libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.c:24:
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:25: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CONFIG_HARDCODED_TABLES 0

In file included from libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:39,
                 from libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.c:24:
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:46:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f20_0_8) [ 8][8][2];
                        ^~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:46:35: error: unknown type name ‘f20_0_8’
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f20_0_8) [ 8][8][2];
                                   ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:47:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_0_12)[12][8][2];
                        ^~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:47:35: error: unknown type name ‘f34_0_12’
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_0_12)[12][8][2];
                                   ^~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:48:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_1_8) [ 8][8][2];
                        ^~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:48:35: error: unknown type name ‘f34_1_8’
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_1_8) [ 8][8][2];
                                   ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:49:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_2_4) [ 4][8][2];
                        ^~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:49:35: error: unknown type name ‘f34_2_4’
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_2_4) [ 4][8][2];
                                   ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:50:36: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static TABLE_CONST DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, Q_fract_allpass)[2][50][3][2];
                                    ^~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:50:47: error: unknown type name ‘Q_fract_allpass’
 static TABLE_CONST DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, Q_fract_allpass)[2][50][3][2];
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:51:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, phi_fract)[2][50][2];
                        ^~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:51:35: error: unknown type name ‘phi_fract’
 static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, phi_fract)[2][50][2];
                                   ^~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h: In function ‘ps_tableinit’:
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:187:13: error: ‘Q_fract_allpass’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             Q_fract_allpass[0][k][m][0] = cos(theta);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:187:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:191:9: error: ‘phi_fract’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         phi_fract[0][k][0] = cos(theta);
         ^~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:210:29: error: ‘f20_0_8’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     make_filters_from_proto(f20_0_8,  g0_Q8,   8);
                             ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:211:29: error: ‘f34_0_12’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     make_filters_from_proto(f34_0_12, g0_Q12, 12);
                             ^~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:212:29: error: ‘f34_1_8’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     make_filters_from_proto(f34_1_8,  g1_Q8,   8);
                             ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.h:213:29: error: ‘f34_2_4’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     make_filters_from_proto(f34_2_4,  g2_Q4,   4);
                             ^~~~~~~
In file included from libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.c:24:
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c: In function ‘main’:
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:88:28: error: ‘f20_0_8’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     ARRAY_RENAME(3d_array)(f20_0_8, 8, 8, 2);
                            ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:91:28: error: ‘f34_0_12’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     ARRAY_RENAME(3d_array)(f34_0_12, 12, 8, 2);
                            ^~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:94:28: error: ‘f34_1_8’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     ARRAY_RENAME(3d_array)(f34_1_8, 8, 8, 2);
                            ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:97:28: error: ‘f34_2_4’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     ARRAY_RENAME(3d_array)(f34_2_4, 4, 8, 2);
                            ^~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:101:28: error: ‘Q_fract_allpass’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     ARRAY_RENAME(4d_array)(Q_fract_allpass, 2, 50, 3, 2);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/aacps_tablegen_template.c:104:28: error: ‘phi_fract’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     ARRAY_RENAME(3d_array)(phi_fract, 2, 50, 2);
                            ^~~~~~~~~
make: *** [ffbuild/common.mak:201: libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error.  If I remove  --enable-hardcoded-tables from when I run configure it goes away.

Comment: @New contributor
You are great man !
I did a quick attempt after removing --enable-hardcoded-tables
This time I didn't get those errors.
How come this issue is not discussed any where and how come ffmpeg communiny not attended this ?

Any side effects exoected after removing --enable-hardcoded-tables ?

Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know the first one.  Seems like a compiler thing maybe syntax -- I get the error on 5.0 and above as I tried different versions.  As for side effects -- still testing it out.

Comment: I made a proper build and tested everything seems ok.
Thanks you so much again !

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct (one line) fix is now the main branch of FFMPEG
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/814178f92647be2411516bbb82f48532373d2554

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on iOS aarch64 (jailbroken) compiling new ffmpeg 6.0.0 in clang-15 when using my known-good ffmpeg config args. So I preprocessed `libavcodec/aacps_tablegen.c` to one file and diff’ed it between last version 5.1.2 which compiled fine, and new 6.0 released today:

```
3298,3303c3313,3318
< static float __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) f20_0_8 [ 8][8][2];
< static float __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) f34_0_12[12][8][2];
< static float __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) f34_1_8 [ 8][8][2];
< static float __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) f34_2_4 [ 4][8][2];
< static float __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) Q_fract_allpass[2][50][3][2];
< static float __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) phi_fract[2][50][2];
---

> static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f20_0_8) [ 8][8][2];
> static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_0_12)[12][8][2];
> static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_1_8) [ 8][8][2];
> static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, f34_2_4) [ 4][8][2];
> static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, Q_fract_allpass)[2][50][3][2];
> static DECLARE_ALIGNED(16, float, phi_fract)[2][50][2];
```

I suspect hardcoded tables will compile if you can find the DECLARE_ALIGNED macro and change it to the old 5.1.2 version in my diff.